# "File's Owner" Disappeared from xib File

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, nib

I have been working on a xib file for a month without any issues.  All of a sudden I opened the file and the "File's Owner" is gone.  I did work on the project between the last time I saw the File's Owner there and the time I opened it and found it was missing.  Is this a bug in XCode?  Is it burried somewhere in my project?  I'd really like to not have to start a new file from scratch and more importantly I'd like to know what happened so that I can prevent it from happening again.  I have not seen any other questions even remotely similar to this.

Using Xcode 5.0

Thanks for any help you can provide.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. That's unusual.

The first thing I'd try is just relaunching Xcode. It might just be confused.

Next I'd look into version control. Check out git diffs and see if it was somehow removed. There should be an entry in the xib file named `IBFilesOwner`. If that disappears at some point in the history, restore it.

If that doesn't help, close the project and then open the xib in a text editor. It should include a couple of lines like this:

```
<placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
<placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
```

If your "file's owner" is really gone, then the first of these two lines will be missing. Put it back and save changes. **But** this is such a weird change that I'd still be suspicious of the file integrity. When you reopen the file in Xcode, check **everything** to make sure no other weird changes have snuck in.

Comment: You were right.  I opened it up in text editor and the first line was missing.  I added it back in and now I have a File's Owner in my nib.  Unfortunately, everything that I had in there was gone.  I have to rebuild the file.  Unfortunately, I never saved / "commit" my older version in git, so I don't have any history to look into to see what happened.  Like you, I am suspicious of the file integrity.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

May be a system restart will help. Xcode gets crazy at times.